# Rxswift hide button inside UITableViewCell after tapped

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a addButton inside a UITableCieCwell. I want the addButton to be disappear after user click it, so I created a Action and bind it to the addButton.

However, all the addButton is disappeared although I just run my app.

I'm very new to RxSwift, please help me out.

**Bind UI**

```
viewModel.courses
        .asObservable()
        .bind(to: collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: AddableCourseCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: AddableCourseCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in

            let action = self.viewModel.actions.value[row]
            action.enabled.asObservable()
                .bind(to: cell.addButton.rx.isHidden)
                .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

            cell.addButton.rx
                .tap
                .debounce(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
                .subscribe({ (event) in

                    action.execute(element)

                }).disposed(by: cell.disposeBag)

        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ViewModel {

    var courses: Variable<[Course]> = Variable([])
    var selectedCourses: Variable<[Course]> = Variable([])
     var actions = Variable<[Action<Course, Bool>]>([])

    private func generateAddActions(courses: [Course]) -> [Action<Course, Bool>] {
        var actions: [Action<Course, Bool>] = []
        for _ in courses {
            let action = Action<Enrollment, Bool>(workFactory: { (input) -> Observable<Bool> in
                let isAdded = selectedCourses.value.contains(input)
                if !isAdded {
                    self.selectedCourses.value.append(input)
                }
                return Observable.just(isAdded)
            })
            actions.append(action)
        }
        return actions
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi one tip I can give you is to add a `.debug()` in the `action` observable so you can see the values emitted. However, I believe what's causing you trouble is that the `action` observable's initial value is `true` which is bounded to the `isHidden` attribute of the `addButton`